# How to split some elements from array by semicolon and add them as new elements to original array

Tags: java

I have for example this array

```
String[] mailToCc = {"chrisdgc794@gmail.com; christian.gamba@cast.com.py;", "notiene@gmail.com"};
```

1st element are 2 mails with a semicolon at the end. What I want is to separate those 2(they can be found on any element of the array, not always the first) and add them to the originl array like new elements.
This is how it should look

```
["chrisdgc794@gmail.com", "christian.gamba@cast.com.py", "notiene@gmail.com"];
```

This is my attempt

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> updatedMailToCc = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] mailToCc = {"chrisdgc794@gmail.com; christian.gamba@cast.com.py;", "notiene@gmail.com"};

        for (String element : mailToCc) {
            String[] splitElements = element.split(";");

            // Add the original element itself
            updatedMailToCc.add(element);

            // If it could be split, add each part as a new element
            if (splitElements.length > 1) {
                 updatedMailToCc.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitElements));
            }
       }

       // Convert the ArrayList back to an array if needed
       mailToCc = updatedMailToCc.toArray(new String[0]);

       // Print the updated array
       System.out.println("resultado =" + Arrays.toString(mailToCc));
    }
}
```

But instead of getting what I need I get this result

```
["chrisdgc794@gmail.com; christian.gamba@cast.com.py;", "chrisdgc794@gmail.com",  "christian.gamba@cast.com.py", "notiene@gmail.com"]
```

Comment: Even though you have two answers, it will be a good lesson to run this code in a debugger. Set a breakpoint early. Then, run the code one-step-at-a-time, observing the values of variables at each step. Debugging is a good skill to have. If you want to become a software developer, or otherwise regularly create software, it will be a necessary skill.

Comment: thanx, I was doing that but I guess I was not doing it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you both add the base element and its decomposition, so you duplicate things that have semicolon

---

Don't bother to check the amount of parts you have, add them all everytime, but not the base element. Also change a bit the regex to avoid keeping space around your emails

```
for (String element : mailToCc) {
    String[] splitElements = element.split("\\s*;\\s*");
    updatedMailToCc.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitElements));
}
```

---

Another way would be to  add the base element conditionaly

```
for (String element : mailToCc) {
    String[] splitElements = element.split("\\s*;\\s*");

    if (splitElements.length > 1) {
         updatedMailToCc.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitElements));
    } else {
         updatedMailToCc.add(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that you are adding the original element to the `updatedMailToCc` list regardless of whether it contains a semicolon or not thats why you are seeing the original string with the semicolons in the result.

To fix this, you should only add the split elements to the `updatedMailToCc` list and skip adding the original element.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> updatedMailToCc = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] mailToCc = {"chrisdgc794@gmail.com; christian.gamba@cast.com.py;", "notiene@gmail.com"};

        for (String element : mailToCc) {
            String[] splitElements = element.split(";");

            // If it could be split, add each part as a new element
            for (String splitElement : splitElements) {
                if (!splitElement.trim().isEmpty()) { // Avoid adding empty strings
                    updatedMailToCc.add(splitElement.trim());
                }
            }
        }

        // Convert the ArrayList back to an array if needed
        mailToCc = updatedMailToCc.toArray(new String[0]);

        // Print the updated array
        System.out.println("resultado = " + Arrays.toString(mailToCc));
    }
}
```